# detect Flash-accessible camera without prompting user for access to camera if one exists

Tags: flash, webcam

From a Flash object, I would like to be able to *detect the presence of* a webcam that the user *might* grant access to, without actually asking the user whether they want to grant access.  This is to streamline a large application that has extra features if a webcam exists — if there is a webcam, the application will present several dialogs that lead up to the normal cam-security prompt, but if the user doesn't have the hardware, I want to skip over them altogether.  Requesting access to the cam before those dialogs won't make sense to the user.

It appears not to be possible to call `Camera.getCamera()` without the security prompt happening.  Is there a workaround?  (For instance, could I, perhaps, call `getCamera` in a hidden Flash object and inspect its return value, or does it block until the user acknowledges the  security prompt?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with Haxe but should be possible with ActionScript 3 too.

```
if (Camera.names.length != 0) {
  // user has camera
  // this triggers the access dialog
  var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
}
else {
  // user has no camera
}
```

Comment: Finally got around to trying this: it works.  And also thank you for putting me on to haXe, now I don't have to struggle with the Flash IDE anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists a workaround right inside the flash or for any web application as the whole point of security (by restricting access to user's devices) would be lost from that.

As far as I know, the only solution for your problem is to ask the user before prompting the camera detection function.

I might sound like a bummer but something like :

- Show Dialog "Do you have a camera?" - Yes/No
- If yes show Dialog "Please grant the
  flash player to access camera..." - OK
- Detect Camera (using the getCamera
  method)
- If failed show Dialog
- else start showing all the several
  dialogs you intended to.

Also sometimes the camera might be present physically & not installed. So if a user does not know or the camera is inaccessible for any reason you might need to figure that out. So for that use

```
flash.media.Camera.names
```

and check if it is empty or not. Or better you could simply pull a few bytes of data from the user's camera & see if it really exists & is accessible.

Comment: I don't see that it defeats security to avoid bothering the user with a prompt about a device they don't have.

Comment: Who said about defeating security. The workaround I proposed is not for the security, its for the job you are trying to accomplish. If flash really had something like that, flash might not have been so popular at all. At least I wouldn't use a thing which allows websites to  automatically learn about devices attached to my pc without me not even knowing about the same.

Answer (score 0):

This might work too:  Capabilities.hasVideoEncoder;

The Camera.names.length approach though seems more reliable (as suggested by Hippo).